# JAVA-ANDROID STUDIO - What arguments should i put to run this method?

Tags: java, android-studio, variables, methods

This has been bugging me for a while already since i couldn't fully grasp how the arguments work.
Can you help me figure out what arguments should i put?
I am trying to pull a variable i stored from another class. So I created a method creating an instance and calling the variable from that class.
But when i try to call the method it asks for arguments

Here is my code, i removed what i believe is non related codes.

My source class where i stored my variables:

```
public class UserProfile {

    private int id;
    private String lname, fname, mname, desig, employee_id;
    private String profileImage;

    public UserProfile(int id, String lname, String fname, String mname, String desig, String employee_id, String profileImage) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.mname = mname;
        this.desig = desig;
        this.employee_id = employee_id;
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public String getMname() {
        return mname;
    }

    public String getDesig() {
        return desig;
    }

    public String getEmployee_id() {
        return employee_id;
    }

    public String getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

}
```

my class where im calling my variables:

```
public class TicketActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spnrViolations, spnrDLtype;
    TextView tvViolation1, tvViolation2, tvViolation3, tvViolation4, tvViolation5;
    ImageButton clearV1, clearV2, clearV3, clearV4, clearV5;
    TextView officerName, officerID, currentDate;


    String violation1TV, violation2TV, violation3TV, violation4TV, violation5TV;
    String clear ="Empty";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket);

        officerName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_ticket_area_officerName);

        loadUser();  //<<<--------- it asks here for an argument that i dont know what to put :(
    } //OnCreate END

    private void loadUser(UserProfile userProfile) {
        String fname, mname, lname;
        fname = userProfile.getFname();
        mname = userProfile.getMname();
        lname = userProfile.getLname();
        String fullname = fname + " " + mname + " " + lname;
        officerName.setText(fullname);

    }
 
}   ////// THIS IS THE END ////////// ------------------------------------>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your `loadUser()` method with `UserProfile` as argument:

```java
private void loadUser(UserProfile userProfile) //here your method require instance of UserProfile
   .... 
}
```

You have to get user from your datasource and put as `UserProfle`. You can use database or List/Map etc. Good way would be create a class `UserProfileService` with List or other collection for storing `UserProfile` instances and implement method `loadUserByUsername(String username)`. It's loose concept, I don't know what exactly do you want to do. 
If you want I can explain and write concept of these method and class.

Comment: hi! thanks for the help! i just want to get the specific variables from my UserProfile class using getter and then setText them to a TextView which in my case the "officerName" in my current activity.
i am also using that UserProfile class on an adapter. ill try to add how i used it on my adapter

Comment: Okay, are you storing users anywhere? To load user you have to have a service with them. I see it as: `loadUser(userProfileService.loadOfficerByName(officerName));`‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎                                      
                    `UserProfileService` will be your "database".

Comment: If they're wanting a user profile service then they will want a ViewModel & Repository. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

Comment: thank you for the help @fr3ddie is "service" a java term? im tried to use the userProfileService.loadOfficerByName you mentioned but i how it works. and on my case i wouldn't work probably because im doing it wrong.

Comment: @Brettins thank you for the help! i admit i was really clueless about what you said until i saw your link. well, im still close to clueless even after going thru the guide. im still studying it. i have a lot more to learn. thank you agian for the linked guide.

Comment: im just trying to call the getFname method from the UserProfile class into my TicketActivity class..
but everytime i create an instance of UserProfile class like:
UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
it asks for arguments which are the values of the constructor on my UserProfile class.
so instead of calling the method from the UserProfile class. it seemed like im actually inserting new data/values in the UserProfile class instead.

Comment: I mean that you must to create a `UserProfileService` (it is only my invented name) with method `loadUserByUsername(String username)` for getting saved users from your data source (`ArrayList` for example). And `saveUser(UserProfile userProfile)` for saving an users. If you will do such service, you can use it for storing the users. Do you understand? If no I can write example code. A little bit I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @JM-tryingToLearn I think given your level of understanding of the Android ecosystem & Java an online course would be your best bet. There is example applications from Google that you should be able to download the code from and copy and paste things that you want. https://developer.android.com/courses

Answer (score 0):

You need a UserProfile argument - the function definition lower shows this - `loadUser(UserProfile userProfile)`. So the line where you're calling it should be something like `loadUser(userProfile)` where `userProfile` is an object you've passed into the activity or called from a singleton.

I can't quite tell if you are trying to create a Singleton (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/) or not. If you want to only have one User Profile loaded, then be able to access it from anywhere, you want a singleton.

However, if you have many UserProfile objects, you will need to pass the object you want to work with to the class that you want to access it with. There are a few ways to pass objects into activities, but it will depend on your project setup.

For some unsought advice, I would advise against variable names like "clearV1" "clearV2". You probably either want a map/collection, or to name these closer to what their actual usage will be.